# Balance procedure of AVL Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

As per my understanding of AVL tree, for every node, heights of left and right subtrees should differ by at most 1.

Here is the code, I came up with to balance the height while inserting a new node. The following method will be executed repeatedly starting from the new node propagating upwards till root

```
private Node balance(Node x) {
    if (Math.abs(height(x.left) - height(x.right)) <= 1) {
        return x;
    }
    // left sub tree is heavier than right sub tree
    if (height(x.left) > height(x.right)) {
        // right sub tree of left sub tree is heavier than left sub tree of left sub tree
        if (height(x.left.left) < height(x.left.right)) {
            leftRotate(x.left);
        }
        return rightRotate(x);
    }
    // right sub tree is heavier than left sub tree
    else {
        // left sub tree of right sub tree is heavier than right sub tree of right sub tree
        if (height(x.right.left) > height(x.right.right)) {
            rightRotate(x.right);
        }
        return leftRotate(x);
    }
}
```

When I looked at [MIT solutions (Page 5)](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/ps5-sol.pdf) ,it seems that they are performing left rotate and then right rotate if node is inserted in the left sub tree of left sub tree of unbalanced node:

[image]

As per my understanding, if we insert a node in left sub tree of left sub tree of unbalanced node, we should me right rotation only, not left rotation and subsequent right rotation.

What am I missing here? Did I implemented it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed found a mistake in the [referenced document](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/ps5-sol.pdf) on page 5.

The pictures on page 4 are correct, but the implementation on page 5 is wrong, probably a typo.

Logically lines lines 4-7 should mirror lines 8-11 in terms of left and right. With that in mind it is apparent there is a mistake there.

Line 5 should have *left* and *right* swapped -- or else use `<` instead of `>` which comes down to the same thing --, like this:

5             **if** *height*(*left*[*y*]) < *height*(*right*[*y*])

Your implementation is correct in that respect.